# Why I Got Compile Error For This?

Tags: java

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    final int x=100;
    final int y;
    y=100;
    int z=100;
    int a,b,c,d;
    if(x>0){a=0;}
    if(y>0){b=0;}
    if(z>0){c=0;}
    if(100>0){d=0;}
    System.out.println(a);//Line 1 
    System.out.println(b);//Line 2
    System.out.println(c);//Line 3
    System.out.println(d);//Line 4
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner in Java.  When I Compile above code, I had an Error message  s in Line 2 & line 3.I want to know the reason for that.

Comment: Please share the error message. When you google for the message you maybe find the solution by yourself.

Comment: what IDE are you using? in eclipse it pops up a red x. if you put your cursor over it, it shows you the obvious. it would do the same in intelliJ. if you're not using either one of these IDEs you should switch. i could tell you the error but you learning how to use the tools of the trade is a much better idea.

Comment: you just initial `int a,b,c,d;` variables with default value.

Comment: @amir110 - it is more complicated than that.  See my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, all local variables declared without an initializer need to be *definitely assigned* before they are used.  For example:

```
int x = 1;
int a;
if (x == 1) {
   a = 1;
}
System.out.println(a);  // ERROR
```

The rules for *definite assignment* are strict.  They basically mean that the assignment must occur for all possible paths through the code *that are allowed by the syntax*.

So in the above, the syntax allows a path where the "then" branch is not executed.  Now you and I know that this is not possible.  But the syntax allows it, and therefore the compiler **must** call this a compilation error.

The rules for definite assignment are set out in excruciating detail in [Chapter 16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-16.html) of the JLS.  The rules for `if` statement are in [16.2.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.7).  If you take the time to read the rules in detail, you will see that declaring `x` as `final` makes `x > 0` a "boolean valued constant expression".  This allows the compiler to determine that `a` in your example is definitely assigned.

The reason that Java has these strict / pedantic rules is so that Java compiler writers don't need to implement complicated (and ultimately intractable) theorem proving logic in the compiler.  For the above example, the proof is simple and obvious, but it is possible to construct examples where it is *mathematically impossible* to prove that an assignment will or won't occur.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize values for variable b and c.

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    final int x=100;
    final int y;
    y=100;
    int z=100;
    int a,b = 0,c = 0,d;
    if(x>0){a=0;}
    if(y>0){b=0;}
    if(z>0){c=0;}
    if(100>0){d=0;}
    System.out.println(a);//Line 1 
    System.out.println(b);//Line 2
    System.out.println(c);//Line 3
    System.out.println(d);//Line 4
    }
}
```